# Nodes with an idea

Tags: nodes

I want to try making a binary tree with the internal nodes in a post order, in byte format.

Like this:

```
leaf_3 = Node(3, None, None)
leaf_2 = Node(2, None, None)
leaf_5 = Node(5, None, None)
```

is equal to [0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5]

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what the input tree looks like. Assuming it is something simple like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

And assuming we're happy to distinguish leaf/non-leaf nodes by checking the instance type in our simple tree:

```
def isNonLeaf(node):
    return isinstance(node, Node)
```

Then you can do a simple post-order traversal and build up your output list (note that mutable default arguments [are a bad idea](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)):

```
def postorder_node(node):
    def recurse(node, node_list):
        if isNonLeaf(node.left):
            node_list.extend([1, recurse(node.left, node_list)])
        else:
            node_list.extend([0, node.left])

        if isNonLeaf(node.right):
            node_list.extend([1, recurse(node.right, node_list)])
        else:
            node_list.extend([0, node.right])
        nextNodeId['v'] += 1
        return nextNodeId['v']
    nextNodeId = {'v': -1}
    node_list = []
    recurse(node, node_list)
    return node_list
```

For your example:

```
node0 = Node(3, 2)
node1 = Node(node0, 5)
print postorder_node(node1)
```

Produces:

```
[0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5]
```

If you show us what the actual input tree looks like and the exact output you desire I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: This is a nice answer, however you're manually setting the node numbers during their construction. @Airisz do you require the node numbers to be computed for you? If not, this solution should be golden for you, otherwise see http://stackoverflow.com/a/38915939/1636276.

Comment: Also +1 for pointing out the problem with using mutable arguments as default values in function definitions.

Comment: The question is a little vague, I've updated my answer to work without explicit node ids anyway as that is likely what was wanted.  Also +1 on your answer, good job :)

Answer (score 1):

Really interesting problem!

I have a solution but I don't understand how you get `[0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5]` (edit: I do now - see update below). I believe that the root node of the left subtree would be numbered 2 if you did a post-order traversal (since its subtrees would be enumerated first), meaning the (top-most) root node's byte representation would be `[1, 2, 0, 5]`. My script gives me `[0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 5]`.

I'm trying to improve my Python skills in preparation for some serious upcoming Python work so my code might not be the best, but I hope this suffices:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int, left_tree, right_tree):
        self.value = value
        self.left_tree = left_tree
        self.right_tree = right_tree
        self.number = None # Set through traversal

    def is_leaf(self) -> bool:
        return not self.has_left_subtree() and not self.has_right_subtree()

    def has_left_subtree(self) -> bool:
        return self.left_tree is not None

    def has_right_subtree(self) -> bool:
        return self.right_tree is not None

    def to_bytes(self) -> [int]:
        """
        Node numbering is calculated through post-order traversal of tree

        left_subtree:        IF left subtree is leaf THEN 0 ELSE 1
        left_subtree-value:  IF left subtree is leaf THEN left child value ELSE left child number
        right_subtree:       IF right subtree is leaf THEN 0 ELSE 1
        right_subtree-value: IF right subtree is leaf THEN right child value ELSE right child number
        """
        # PRE: node numbers should have been calculated
        assert self.number is not None

        # Base case.
        if self.is_leaf():
            return []

        # Recursive case.
        else:
            assert self.left_tree.number is not None
            assert self.right_tree.number is not None

            left_byte_repr = self.left_tree.to_bytes() if self.has_left_subtree() else []
            right_byte_repr = self.right_tree.to_bytes() if self.has_right_subtree() else []

            self_byte_repr = [0 if self.left_tree.is_leaf() else 1,
                         self.left_tree.value if self.left_tree.is_leaf() else self.left_tree.number,
                         0 if self.right_tree.is_leaf() else 1,
                         self.right_tree.value if self.right_tree.is_leaf() else self.right_tree.number]

            # Post-order construction.
            return left_byte_repr + right_byte_repr + self_byte_repr

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node {}: value={}, left tree=[{}], right tree=[{}]".format(self.number, self.value, self.left_tree, self.right_tree)


def post_order_enumerate_tree(tree : Node) -> Node:
    enumerated_tree, _ = post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree, 0)
    return enumerated_tree


def post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree: Node, curr_node_number: int) -> (Node, int):
    # Base case.
    if tree.is_leaf():
        tree.number = curr_node_number
        return tree, curr_node_number + 1

    # Recursive case.
    else:
        # Traverse left subtree, if it exists.
        if tree.has_left_subtree():
            enumerated_left_tree, new_node_number = post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree.left_tree, curr_node_number)
            tree.left_tree = enumerated_left_tree
            curr_node_number = new_node_number

        # Traverse right subtree, if it exists.
        if tree.has_right_subtree():
            enumerated_right_tree, new_node_number = post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree.right_tree, curr_node_number)
            tree.right_tree = enumerated_right_tree
            curr_node_number = new_node_number

        # Operate on this node itself.
        tree.number = curr_node_number
        return tree, curr_node_number + 1


def build_tree() -> Node:
    leaf_3 = Node(3, None, None)
    leaf_2 = Node(2, None, None)
    leaf_5 = Node(5, None, None)

    tree_a = Node(None, leaf_3, leaf_2)
    root = Node(None, tree_a, leaf_5)
    return root


def main():
    tree = build_tree()
    enumerated_tree = post_order_enumerate_tree(tree)

    print(enumerated_tree.to_bytes())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Tree Construction**

For this example I created the same tree as you gave in the question:

```
leaf_3 = Node(3, None, None)
leaf_2 = Node(2, None, None)
leaf_5 = Node(5, None, None)

tree_a = Node(None, leaf_3, leaf_2)
root = Node(None, tree_a, leaf_5)
```

**Enumerated Tree Structure**

Here's the structure of the tree I got after assigning numbers to each node:

[image: enumerated tree structure]

**Output**

The byte representation of this tree according to my script: `[0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, 5]`

**Assumptions**

This is what I understood from reading your post or otherwise assumed.

- Nodes must either be leaves or have two child nodes (single subtree case isn't defined by your rules).
- Enumeration of nodes is done **post-order**.
- Enumeration is 0-indexed (i.e. first node is assigned number `0`).
- Recursive construction of node byte representations is done **post-order**.
- Node byte representation:

  - `byte 1 = left subtree is leaf ? 0 : 1`
  - `byte 2 = left subtree is leaf ? left subtree value : left subtree number`
  - `byte 3 = right subtree is leaf ? 0 : 1`
  - `byte 4 = right subtree is leaf ? right subtree value : right subtree number`

---

## Update

I realise now that you're getting `[0, 3, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5]` because you're not including leaf nodes in the enumeration. I updated the code to allow you to choose whether or not to enumerate leaves. When `enumerate_leaves` is `True`, it will give the result I originally got (shown above). When set `False`, it will give the result that you and FujiApple got.

Here's the code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int, left_tree, right_tree):
        self.value = value
        self.left_tree = left_tree
        self.right_tree = right_tree
        self.number = None # Set through traversal

    def is_leaf(self) -> bool:
        return not self.has_left_subtree() and not self.has_right_subtree()

    def has_left_subtree(self) -> bool:
        return self.left_tree is not None

    def has_right_subtree(self) -> bool:
        return self.right_tree is not None

    def to_bytes(self) -> [int]:
        """
        Node numbering is calculated through post-order traversal of tree

        left_subtree:        IF left subtree is leaf THEN 0 ELSE 1
        left_subtree-value:  IF left subtree is leaf THEN left child value ELSE left child number
        right_subtree:       IF right subtree is leaf THEN 0 ELSE 1
        right_subtree-value: IF right subtree is leaf THEN right child value ELSE right child number
        """

        # Base case.
        if self.is_leaf():
            return []

        # Recursive case.
        else:
            assert self.number is not None

            left_byte_repr = self.left_tree.to_bytes() if self.has_left_subtree() else []
            right_byte_repr = self.right_tree.to_bytes() if self.has_right_subtree() else []

            self_byte_repr = [0 if self.left_tree.is_leaf() else 1,
                         self.left_tree.value if self.left_tree.is_leaf() else self.left_tree.number,
                         0 if self.right_tree.is_leaf() else 1,
                         self.right_tree.value if self.right_tree.is_leaf() else self.right_tree.number]

            # Post-order construction.
            return left_byte_repr + right_byte_repr + self_byte_repr

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node {}: value={}, left tree=[{}], right tree=[{}]".format(self.number, self.value, self.left_tree, self.right_tree)


def post_order_enumerate_tree(tree : Node,  enumerate_leaves: bool=False) -> Node:
    enumerated_tree, _ = post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree, 0, enumerate_leaves)
    return enumerated_tree


def post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree: Node, curr_node_number: int, enumerate_leaves: bool) -> (Node, int):
    # Base case.
    if tree.is_leaf():
        if enumerate_leaves:
            tree.number = curr_node_number
            return tree, curr_node_number + 1
        else:
            return tree, curr_node_number

    # Recursive case.
    else:
        # Traverse left subtree, if it exists.
        if tree.has_left_subtree():
            enumerated_left_tree, new_node_number = post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree.left_tree, curr_node_number, enumerate_leaves)
            tree.left_tree = enumerated_left_tree
            curr_node_number = new_node_number

        # Traverse right subtree, if it exists.
        if tree.has_right_subtree():
            enumerated_right_tree, new_node_number = post_order_enumerate_tree_helper(tree.right_tree, curr_node_number, enumerate_leaves)
            tree.right_tree = enumerated_right_tree
            curr_node_number = new_node_number

        # Operate on this node itself.
        tree.number = curr_node_number
        return tree, curr_node_number + 1


def build_tree() -> Node:
    leaf_3 = Node(3, None, None)
    leaf_2 = Node(2, None, None)
    leaf_5 = Node(5, None, None)

    tree_a = Node(None, leaf_3, leaf_2)
    root = Node(None, tree_a, leaf_5)
    return root


def main():
    tree = build_tree()
    enumerated_tree = post_order_enumerate_tree(tree, enumerate_leaves=False)

    print(enumerated_tree.to_bytes())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```